# Different date in Excel export file. Why do they differ by 1 day?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I am exporting an Excel file (.xls) and there are three date columns among other data in the export.
The date values in the columns of the Excel file differs by one day, and I have no clue why?!?!?!
I have debuged the lines in the Java code and the date is defently the 1st August 2013 but in the Excel file the same date is shown as the 31st July 2013.
I have debugged my code and the date is 100% the 1st August.
So why the date in the Excel is the 31st July 2013. There is a difference of 1 damn day...

In these lines:

```
...
case "java.sql.Timestamp":
{
    ws.addCell(new  jxl.write.DateTime((i), row, new java.util.Date(((java.sqlTimestamp) o).getTime())));
    break;
}
...
```

The date is the 1st August 2013. In Excel there is written the 31st July 2013. 1 day differnce...
But why? Do you maybe have an explanation for that?

Best regards

Comment: Maybe a timezone issue?

Comment: The most obvious suspect would be a timezone mismatch. Check the time portion of the date.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answers but where or how can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution.
1st I changed the Excel format from xsl to xslx.
2nd I used a CellStyle format like this:

```
CellStyle dateStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
dateStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"));
...
case "java.sql.Timestamp":
{
  cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
  cell.setCellValue(new Date(((Timestamp) o).getTime()));
  break;
}
```

Now it is working... Very strange, because I am not sure why... it is working...